# psycopg2 issue on import csv

Tags: python, file, psycopg2

```
def import_from_csv(common_cols_tup, table_name):
"""

:param common_cols_tup: tuple of all columns
:param table_name: database table name
:return:
"""
with open('/tmp/%s.csv'%table_name, 'r') as f:
    # Notice that we don't need the `csv` module.
    next(f)  # Skip the header row.
    dest_cur.copy_from(f, table_name, sep=";",null='\\N', columns=common_cols_tup)
dest_cur.commit()
```

> I am getting following trace on trying this piece of code
>
> File "migrate.py", line 29, in import_from_csv
>       dest_cur.copy_from(f, table_name, sep=";",null='\N', columns=common_cols_tup)
>   psycopg2.extensions.QueryCanceledError: COPY from stdin failed: error in .read() call: exceptions.ValueError Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
>   CONTEXT:  COPY res_partner, line 1

Answer (score 0):

The key is the inner error:

```
exceptions.ValueError Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

According to [this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33891347/2715819), the error comes from using both `next` and `readline`on the same file handle.  If you use `readline` to skip the header line you I think should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like

```
def import_from_csv(common_cols_tup, table_name):
    """

    :param common_cols_tup: tuple of all columns
    :param table_name: database table name
    :return:
    """
    with open('/tmp/%s.csv'%table_name, 'r') as f:
        # Notice that we don't need the `csv` module.
        next(f)  # Skip the header row.
        content = StringIO('\n'.join(line for line in f))
        dest_cur.copy_from(content, table_name, sep=";",null='\\N', columns=common_cols_tup)
    dest_cur.commit()
```